# Combobox items does not display title in C# WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have main view model which contains:

```
public class MainViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public MainViewModel() { Categories = LoadCategories(); }
   public ObservableCollection<CategoryViewModel> Categories {get;}
   public FileData Data {get; set;}
}

public class FileData: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public string Title {get {...} set {...}}
   public CategoryViewModel Category {get {...} set{...}}
}
```

and

```
public class CategoryViewModel
{
   public string Title {get;set;}
   public EMyEnum Value {get;set;}
}
```

and xaml:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="16"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Data.Category, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
              DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Title}"/>
```

Seems that dropdown list does not show `Title` value. In debug, the `Title` is populated and is not empty.

If I remove `DisplayMemberPath` then in list will display full namespace to `CategoryViewModel` class.

What can do here ? Where's my mistake ?

Answer (score 3):

DisplayMemberPath doesnt require binding . We just need to specify the property name

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="16"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Data.Category, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
              DisplayMemberPath="Title"/>
```